# Algorithm for regular continued fraction of a square root

Tags: algorithms, roots, radicals, continued-fractions

Say I have a number $n$, and want to find the expression of $\sqrt{n}$ as a [regular continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularContinuedFraction.html). How would I do such a thing systematically? 
A naive computer algorithm wouldn't work, due to floating point errors.

Comment: The algorithm is described here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Continued_fraction_expansion

Comment: It doesn't always produce a **regular** continued fraction. for example when $S=7$

Comment: Then, please show what the algorithm gives and what would be the correct result.

Comment: Is $n$ assumed to be a positive integer?

Comment: it gives $a=\sqrt4=2$, $r=3$ (because $S=7=\lfloor\sqrt7\rfloor^2+3=4+3$), and that means $\sqrt7=2+\frac3{4+\frac3{4+\frac3{4+\frac3{...}}}}$, while the desired result is one in which the first element is $\lfloor\sqrt7\rfloor=2$, and all the numerators are 1.     
And yes, $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Maybe, you have chosen the wrong algorithm. I have not further checked the site, but I still think that the algorithm for a regular continued fraction should be present.

Comment: See the algorithm for which Wikipedia uses $\sqrt{114}$ as an example.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly :) but why is $d_{n+1}$ always an integer? You'd intuitively think $d_n$ doesn't necessarily devide $S-m_{n+1}^2$.